# macOS: run user-mode services but allow other users to login

Tags: macos, mac, services, auto-login, fast-user-switching

i would like to run `gitlab-runner` or a multi-user Mac Studio .

Reading the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/osx.html#limitations-on-macos), it seems that I have to setup auto-login for the user who is running `gitlab-runner` as a user-service, in order to make it actually run.

The problem is, that the machine is not dedicated to that single task, but other users might want to use it in the meantime.
So I would like the machine at startup to automatically enable the user-service (e.g. by setting up an auto-login for the given user), and then have the desktop return to the login-screen for others to use the machine.

My gut feeling tells me, that this could be done by autostarting the "Fast User Switch" (after the user-service).
I don't really want the login session of the user running the service to be visible to other users)

Since I'm no expert on macOS, I would be interested in how to do this.
(if there's some other/better way to start a user-service while still allowing other users to log in without them controlling the user's session, i'm very open to it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the Mac to auto-login, then start screensaver quickly and require password after a very short time, then although the initial login account will be presented as first option, any user unable to log into that could switch to their own user from the same interface.

The original account will continue to run in the background, inaccessible to unauthorised standard users - however, any other admin account could access the file-system & any other sudo-enabled structure. FileVault, if enabled, will be unlocked by the first auto-login.

[image]

In Ventura, the pref is in 'Lock Screen' [prior to the 'let's turn macOS into iOS' madness, it was in Security & Privacy]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Following Tetsujin's answer, it seems the *fastest* way to lock the screen is by enabling the screen-locked feature for autologin users:

```sh
defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow autoLoginUserScreenLocked -bool true
```

shamelessly taken from [Mac OS X - auto login followed by immediate activation of screen saver](https://superuser.com/questions/184277)